# How does the 20 minute OOT run work?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time, speedrun

I've just got done watching a sub-20 minute run of The Legend of Zelda, Ocarina Of Time and I need to be explained something.

How in the hell can you Warp form the first boss to the last boss. Happens at about 10 minutes in the video below.

http://www.polygon.com/2015/1/2/7481395/watch-the-fastest-ocarina-of-time-speedrun-ever

I watched the Cosmo Run, but still, can't really understand how that glitch works.  How does it effect the game code in such a way that it warps you from the first boss to a dead Ganon.

Basically, I need an Explain Me Like I'm 5 here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "wrong-warping" happen, and how can I do it myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120422/how-does-wrong-warping-happen-and-how-can-i-do-it-myself)